# Como quitar el efecto de seleccionado de un botón

Tags: css, html5, angular, diseño

Estoy usando ng-bootstrap por lo cual implemente un modal, mi problema es de que no puedo quitar el sombreado blanco que aparece en el contorno del botón cerrar del modal,

Cuando abro el modal ya esta activado el efecto del sombreado blanco pero cuando doy click en alguna otra parte se quita por lo cual solo quiero que ese efecto se muestre cuando es presionado ese botón

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Anexo el código

HTML

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h5 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Editar Empleado</h5>
    <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss()"></button>

  </div>
```

.TS

```
 openModal(empleado: Empleado) {
    const { email, nombre, usuario, status: { descripcion, id_status }, num_empleado, id_empleado } = empleado
    this.id_empleado = id_empleado
    this.formGroupEmpleado.setValue({
      nombre: nombre,
      email: email,
      num_empleado: num_empleado,
      status: {
        id_status: id_status,
        descripcion: descripcion,
      },
      usuario: usuario
    })
    this.modalService.open(this.addview,{ centered: true }).result.then((result) => {
      console.log(result)
    }, (reason) => {
      console.log(reason)
    });
  }
```

Utilice la consola de Chrome y seleccione el elemento y al aplicar el focus como se muestra aquí se eliminaba pero no pude implementarlo en mi css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso te ocurre porque el foco se situa sobre ese elemento por los motivos que sea (no ocurre normalmente, y también se puede dar el caso si usas la tecla TAB para moverte por el modal).

Puedes desactivarlo sin perder la funcionalidad del click usando el atributo [tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex) con valor `-1` para ello sobre el elemento:

```html
<button tabindex="-1" type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="modal.dismiss()"></button>
```

Comment: No entendí mucho como funciona el tabindex, pero funciono de manera perfecta para lo que requería, se que es para los focos pero no lo entiendo...

Comment: Cuando te mueves entre campos input lo puedes hacer mediante la tecla TAB del teclado.  Ese efecto también puede hacerse sobre botones que pueden ser seleccionados, y en tu caso se estaba activando al mostrar el modal sobre el boton X (cerrar), por lo tanto usar tabindex="-1"  es la forma de desactivarlo (ojo con los efectos colaterales, pues si lo pones las personas que no usan ratón no podran acceder al boton Cerrar del modal... otra solución seria forzar el foco en otro campo o botón al mostrar el modal en lugar del botón X)

Comment: Muy bien me quedo mas claro, muchas gracias!